# Webpack setup, webpack doesn't resolve(pack into bundle) css files

Tags: python, django, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I have problem inserting css inside my react code. Problem is that webpack not resolving css files. 
I did everything according to docs, and no luck. Also could be issue that i'm using django 1.9 for this

File structure:

```
webpack.config.js
static
├── bundles
│   └── reqct-25186f952a42614d1bdc.js
├── css
│   ├── tabs.css
│   └── testings.css
└── js
    ├── env_tab.js
    ├── envs.jsx
    └── index.jsx
```

Here is my webpack config:

```js
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        reqct: './static/js'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./static/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
    },

    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({
            filename: './webpack-stats.json'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            allChunks: true
        })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    }
};
```

Dependencies installed:

```
"babel-core": "^6.13.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"jquery": "^3.1.0",
"react": "^15.3.0",
"react-dom": "^15.3.0",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"webpack": "^1.13.1",
"webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.93"
```

Error msg:

```
ERROR in ./static/js/envs.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./testings.css in /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js
resolve file
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css doesn't exist
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.js doesn't exist
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.jsx doesn't exist
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.css doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css doesn't exist (directory default file)
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css]
[/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.js]
[/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.jsx]
[/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.css]
 @ ./static/js/envs.jsx 6:14-43
```

I tried to add one more entry point:

```
css: './static/css'
```

and now errors are:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory './static/css' in /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool
resolve directory ./static/css in /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/css/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  directory default file index
    resolve file index in /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/css
      /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/css/index doesn't exist
      /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/css/index.js doesn't exist
      /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/css/index.jsx doesn't exist
      /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/css/index.css doesn't exist

ERROR in ./static/js/envs.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./testings.css in /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js
resolve file
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css doesn't exist
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.js doesn't exist
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.jsx doesn't exist
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.css doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css doesn't exist (directory default file)
  /Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css]
[/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.js]
[/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.jsx]
[/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/static/js/testings.css.css]
 @ ./static/js/envs.jsx 6:14-43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error messages, it looks like you're trying to include `./testings.css` in the file `static/js/envs.jsx`, so Webpack is (understandably) trying to find that CSS file in `static/js`:

> .../**static/js/testings.css** doesn't exist

Try including `../css/testings.css` instead.

Comment: no luck, just another error msg:
**ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./static/css/testings.css
Module build failed: CssSyntaxError: /css-loader!/Users/ievgeniivdovenko/workspace/personal/tool/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js**

here how i import:

`var testing = require("css!../css/testings.css");`

Comment: That suggests that your CSS is faulty, which is a different issue.

Comment: i also thought so, but this file is empty(testings.css), if i add some simple css like: `a {  background-color: #ddd; }` - same error

Comment: If you're configuring a loader for CSS files in your Webpack config, you probably shouldn't declare a loader in the `require` statement: `require('../css/testings.css')`.

Comment: without declaring in require i have another error: `78% additional chunk assetsTypeError: path.replace is not a function`

Comment: Try `new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css', { allChunks: true })`